# Can't get get mocking ECMAScript Modules in Jest to work

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to run a basic test of a controller for a simply Node.js website application I'm building as a first programming project. I'm using ECMAScript Modules because of the benefits and want to use jest since it's currently the dominate javascript test framework. I followed the instructions in the jest docs for testing ECMAScript Modules (https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) and I'm running the latest jest and stable node version, but I keep getting a type error when I run the test. Tests that don't rely on mocked modules work fine.

The module I am trying to test (homeController.js):

```
import { getHomeAll } from "./homeModel.js";

const displayHomeAction = async (request, response) => {
    const homeData = await getHomeAll();
    response.render('header', homeData)
}

export {displayHomeAction};
```

The test case I am trying to run (homeController.test.js):

```
import {describe, expect, it, jest} from '@jest/globals';
import { displayHomeAction } from '../homeController.js';

jest.unstable_mockModule('../homeModel.js', async () => {
    getHomeAll: jest.fn();
});

const {getHomeAll} = await import('../homeModel.js');

describe('displayHomeAction', () => {
    it('should call getHomeAll', () => {
        const req = new Request("http://localhost:8080/");
        const resp = {
            render: jest.fn(),
        };
        displayHomeAction(req,resp);
        expect(getHomeAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Error I get in gitbash when I run the test suites:

```
 FAIL  Home/__tests__/homeController.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
        at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

       6 | });
       7 |
    >  8 | const {getHomeAll} = await import('../homeModel.js');
         |                      ^
       9 |
      10 | describe('displayHomeAction', () => {
      11 |     it('should call getHomeAll', () => {

      at Runtime.importMock (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:771:16)
      at Home/__tests__/homeController.test.js:8:22
```